# Is there any way to know how long has my application been installed in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, duration

I am looking for a way to know how long has my application been installed in the phone,
i find a way to know when my application were installed but i think this info can't help me because if the user change the phone date when he installed the application a problem will occurs can any body help,I appreciate your help.

Comment: If you don't want fake date by user, provide a backend server and save first user login time and get time from your server not user phone.

Comment: i want my application to be offline

Comment: So you have to accept the fake date by user